# How to find the processor / chip architecture on Linux

Tags: linux

What command should I use to find the processor / chip architecture on Linux?

```
linux-x86-32
linux-x86-64
linux-ppc-64
```

Comment: `uname -m` gives you back `i686` or `x86_64` depending on 32-bit or 64-bit Intel CPU, but I don't have access to machines on non-Intel architectures.

Comment: uname -m says i686. How do I know if its 32 or 64 bit?

Comment: x86_64 or amd64 would be 64-bit. i386, i486, i586, and i686 are 32-bit. Keep in mind however that those values are merely a reflection of the target the kernel was compiled for and not necessarily what the CPU is capable of.

Comment: To know the current architecture of your OS type: `getconf -a | grep LONG_BIT`

Answer (score 72, accepted):

To display kernel architecture: `uname -p`

To display extended CPU details: `cat /proc/cpuinfo`

Comment: More specifically, `uname -p` for processor architecture.

Comment: `uname` (with *any* options) will only show the *kernel* architecture, not the physical CPU architecture. In other words, it will show which CPU the kernel was compiled for. But that could show i386 even when running on a x86_64 CPU.

Comment: `uname -p` gives me `unknown`

Answer (score 32):

In the terminal, type

```
lscpu
```

which returns output like this:

```
Architecture:          i686
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                2
On-line CPU(s) list:   0,1
Thread(s) per core:    1
Core(s) per socket:    2
Socket(s):             1
Vendor ID:             GenuineIntel
CPU family:            6
Model:                 23
Stepping:              6
CPU MHz:               2670.000
BogoMIPS:              5320.13
L1d cache:             32K
L1i cache:             32K
L2 cache:              3072K
```

To only get the architecture:

```
lscpu | grep Architecture
```

Which in this case is

```
Architecture:          i686
```

See [`man lscpu`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/lscpu.1.html) for more.

Answer (score 28):

I'm surprised no one suggested `uname -m`. On my laptop, this gives `armv7l`, while `uname -a` gives me a monstrous two lines of text.

Comment: Possible values listed at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45125516/possible-values-for-uname-m

Comment: lscpu works if installed, but that does not seem available on MacOS or many container images. I have found that "uname -m" seems far more widely available by default, so I would consider that to be the preferred solution.

Answer (score 10):

see (`man uname`):

```
echo `uname -s`-`uname -p`
```

Answer (score 7):

A concise command producing information about the current machine is [`hostnamectl`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/hostnamectl.1.html). Example output:

```
Static hostname: xxxx
Icon name: computer-laptop
Chassis: laptop
Boot ID: b3a1f952c514411c8c4xxxxxxxxxxxx
Operating System: Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS
Kernel: Linux 3.19.0-43-generic
Architecture: x86_64
```

It gives you the most basic information about your machine. Other commands like `uname`, `lsb_release`, or `lscpu` return more specific information.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `lscpu` with grep to get only architecture.

```
lscpu | grep Architecture | awk {'print $2'}
```

Example output:

```
x86_64
```