# Select CPU type to install right flavor of FAX for asterisk

Tags: gcc, cpu, asterisk

(Related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7066625/647991) question, but not exactly the same)

In order to install FAX for asterisk, I need to [select](http://my.digium.com/en/docs/FAX/faa-download/) my cpu type. I have the following options:

- barcelona
- nocona
- core2
- generic
- opteron
- opteron_sse3

I guess this refers to a [GCC flag CPU_TYPE](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.5.3/gcc/i386-and-x86_002d64-Options.html). My system gives me this:

```
root@host1:~# lscpu 
Architecture:          x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
CPU(s):                4
Thread(s) per core:    1
Core(s) per socket:    4
CPU socket(s):         1
NUMA node(s):          1
Vendor ID:             GenuineIntel
CPU family:            6
Model:                 26
Stepping:              5
CPU MHz:               2132.901
Virtualization:        VT-x
L1d cache:             32K
L1i cache:             32K
L2 cache:              256K
L3 cache:              4096K

root@host1:~# cat /proc/cpuinfo 
processor       : 0
vendor_id       : GenuineIntel
cpu family      : 6
model           : 26
model name      : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           E5506  @ 2.13GHz
stepping        : 5
cpu MHz         : 2132.901
cache size      : 4096 KB
physical id     : 0
siblings        : 4
core id         : 0
cpu cores       : 4
apicid          : 0
initial apicid  : 0
fpu             : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level     : 11
wp              : yes
flags           : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf pni dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm dca sse4_1 sse4_2 popcnt lahf_lm dts tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid
bogomips        : 4265.80
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 40 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:
...
```

(In all 4 cores)

But nowhere I see any reference to `barcelona/opteron/...`. How can I find out what is my CPU_TYPE?

Comment: A downvote without comment? Go figure ...

Answer (score 0):

That one cpu

http://ark.intel.com/products/37096/Intel-Xeon-Processor-E5506-4M-Cache-2_13-GHz-4_80-GTs-Intel-QPI

have core2 core.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it still works (older project), but for this case specific to Asterisk, you can use `benchfax` to test each architecture and figure out which one works best. Get it from http://downloads.digium.com/pub/telephony/fax/benchfax/

This [README](http://downloads.digium.com/pub/telephony/fax/README) has more information.