# Finding out type of assembly language generated by `gcc hello_world.c -S`

Tags: c, gcc, assembly

**hello_world.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    printf("Hello World\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Running `gcc hello_world.c -S` generates a `hello_world.s` file in assembly language.

**hello_world.s**

```
    .file   "hello_world.c"
    .section    .rodata
.LC0:
    .string "Hello World"
    .text
    .globl  main
    .type   main, @function
main:
.LFB0:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset 6, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
    movl    $.LC0, %edi
    call    puts
    movl    $0, %eax
    popq    %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE0:
    .size   main, .-main
    .ident  "GCC: (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3"
    .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

Is there some way to find out in what type of assembly language the code was generated in (besides knowing the syntax of all assembly languages.)?

**Reference for myself or anyone else who didn't know this:**

To get your processor architecture run the [following](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7066625/how-to-find-the-linux-processor-chip-architecture):

`uname -p`

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1289881/using-gcc-to-produce-readable-assembly

Comment: For x86 and x86_64 targets you can control the format of the assembly output using `-masm=att` or `-masm=intel`.

Comment: Could you give some example inputs and outputs to clarify what you are looking for?

Comment: @DavidGrayson : See the edit of the original question.

Comment: The first hit on Google: [gcc+assembler+syntax+site:gnu.org](https://www.google.com/search?q=gcc+assembler+syntax+site:gnu.org).

Answer (score 2):

It is the AT&T syntax for the GNU assembler of the target code's CPU by default.  There are options to alter that.

Comment: I don't understand. I thought computers with different CPU architectures used different types of assembly languages. How can they all use AT&T syntax? Or do you mean that the gcc command always generates AT&T syntax regardless of your architecture?

Comment: An assembled file is in binary.  An assembly file is text.  The AT&T syntax describes the way the assembly file is written, it's architecture independent.  The actual instructions in the assembly file are what differs from arch to arch.